# How to list items in props variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the easiest way to list and iterate variable keys and values in props variable?

I can't use `PureComponent` and I should check varibales in  `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can map over it e.g.

```
for (let key in nextProps) {
    const value = nextProps[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily iterate through any object keys using `Object.keys(pros)` which will return array of object keys. And through that you can iterate the key values